# writing html & js code in rich text editor in hippo, so the code functionality will reflect on site

Tags: hippocms

iam new in hippo cms. Is there any way to write html or java script code in rich text editor in hippo cms. so the functionality of any code (html or js) should reflect on pages of site.

```
 function onclick(){
     alert('hello');
}
```

This code should be add in rich text editor and on button click hello should be show on page.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by default js will be removed from rich text fields. While the behavior can be disabled, generally speaking it is not recommended. This requires your editors to know not only JS/Html but also the interactions with your existing templates. It also allows attack vectors from inside your content, though for this they need access to the cms.

https://www.onehippo.org/library/concepts/document-types/html-fields/html-cleaning.html

Comment: Is there any way where I can have an editor on pages, so that we can easily write html and js code and it will reflect on page.(any third party editor will do).

Comment: You can use the rich text editor if you disable html cleaning of the js. Or you can create a document with a text field which you include on your template.